# Unable to read full text from PDF Metadata "Keywords" using iText7

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, itext7

I have written console application(C#) for set/reading PDF Metadata using iText7.
I able to set Keywords properties value but when tried to read values from Keywords properties it return less character.

Below is PDF screenshot,

[image]

Here is console output,

[image]

As you can see difference in output, ***PdfDocumentInfo.GetKeywords()*** returning >> *;TEST1;TEST1* instead of *";TEST1;TEST1_xyz"; TEST1; TEST1*

Is there any solution to fetch full text from ***Keywords*** properties.

thanks in advance!

Technical Details:

.NET Framework - v4.0 ; iText7 - v7.1.0.0